# Android 6 problema com mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-permission

Estou com um problema nas api 23+ do google especificamente no método `mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Necessita de permissão para executar e, no android 6.0+, eu não consigo implementar  o novo método de permissões.

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mapa = googleMap;
    mapa.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());
    verificaConexao();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "versão 0.007", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                TEMPO_MINIMO_UPDATE,
                DISTANCIA_MINIMA_PARA_UPDATE,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );  //LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER ou LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ou LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER

    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Minha localização entrou em catch" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o aplicativo precisa acessar a localização do usuário, é necessário solicitar permissão adicionando a permissão de localização do Android relevante ao aplicativo.

Adicione as permissões ao manifesto do aplicativo

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Solicitar permissões em tempo de execução

O Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) introduziu um novo modelo de processamento de permissões que otimiza o processo para usuários quando instalam e atualizam aplicativos. Se o aplicativo é direcionado ao nível da API 23 ou mais recente, você pode usar o novo modelo de permissões.

crie a classe PermitirLocalização **A classe mostrará o dialogo e informações necessárias que o úsuario precisa saber.

```
public class PermitirLocalizacao {

public static void requestPermission(MapsActivity activity, int requestId,
                                     String permission, boolean finishActivity) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {
        PermitirLocalizacao.RationaleDialog.newInstance(requestId, finishActivity)
                .show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, requestId);

    }
}

public static boolean isPermissionGranted(String[] grantPermissions, int[] grantResults,
                                          String permission) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grantPermissions.length; i++) {
        if (permission.equals(grantPermissions[i])) {
            return grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static class PermissionDeniedDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY = "finish";

    private boolean mFinishActivity = false;

    public static PermissionDeniedDialog newInstance(boolean finishActivity) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY, finishActivity);

        PermissionDeniedDialog dialog = new PermissionDeniedDialog();
        dialog.setArguments(arguments);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mFinishActivity = getArguments().getBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("Este exemplo requere uma permissão para acessar \\'a minha localização\\' layer. Please try again and grant access to use the location.\\nIf the permission has been permanently denied, it can be enabled from the System Settings &gt; Apps &gt; \\'Google Maps API Demos\\'")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (mFinishActivity) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "A permissão é necessária para continuar.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
}

public static class RationaleDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = "requestCode";

    private static final String ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY = "finish";

    private boolean mFinishActivity = false;

    public static RationaleDialog newInstance(int requestCode, boolean finishActivity) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
        arguments.putBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY, finishActivity);
        RationaleDialog dialog = new RationaleDialog();
        dialog.setArguments(arguments);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        final int requestCode = arguments.getInt(ARGUMENT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        mFinishActivity = arguments.getBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("O acesso ao serviço de localização é necessário para demonstrar a funcionalidade.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},                              requestCode);
                        mFinishActivity = false;
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        if (mFinishActivity) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "permissão Localização é necessário para esta demonstração",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Na sua activity do mapa:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    enableMyLocation();
}


private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PermitirLocalizacao.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
    } else if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }

    if (PermitirLocalizacao.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        enableMyLocation();
    } else {resume.
        mPermissionDenied = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    if (mPermissionDenied) {
        showMissingPermissionError();
        mPermissionDenied = false;
    }
}

private void showMissingPermissionError() {
    PermitirLocalizacao.PermissionDeniedDialog
            .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

Esse código resolveu o meu problema, espero que resolva o seu também, forte abraço.

Fonte: [Google Android developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location?hl=pt-br)

Comment: muito obrigado maico resposta perfeita